# How can I customize the progress bar of MPMoviePlayerController's background and behavior?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, controls, mpmovieplayercontroller, customization

Since I'm new I can't post image yet... so I'll have to draw the picture:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|[Done]                        Loading... (*)                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                      |--------------------------|                       |
|                      |                          |                       |
|                      |   |<<      ||      >>|   |                       |
|                      |                          |                       |
|                      |--------------------------|                       |
|                                                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to create a customized MPMoviePlayerController looks like above.

The status bar's background has been changed, and the other thing is it shows the "Done" button even when the player is still loading the movie so that the user can cancel the loading (normal behavior of MPMoviePlayerController is to show the "Done" button after the movie starts to play). Believe it or not, the (*) is the activity indicator.

I may be wrong, but I think I read somewhere in Apple's document that one can't modify any of the subviews of MPMoviePlayerController, so I'm wondering if anyone has done anything like this before?

Comment: You *must* not modify the appearance of the standard controls of MPMoviePlayerConrtoller. There are ways to accomplish modifications but I would strongly advise you to not even attempt it. However, the right solution is to present entirely custom controls as drafted by Jano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pragmatic iPad Programming](http://pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming) has a sample of a custom view/viewController combo done with `MPMoviePlayerController`. Check the source code for chapter 8 (free download from that page). They use a video provided as a file inside the project. Btw, if the file in the video appears red in XCode, you'll have to remove it and add it again, I think the project definition is a bit screwed.

[image]
Not exactly what you asked for but it will set you in the right track.

Comment: there's a tut here as well on how to implement the timeline control: http://blog.engage-encore.com/index.php/2010/11/08/video-player-ipad-iphone/