# How to show the current progress of the video played using MPMoviePlayer in a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, video, uilabel, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to show the **current Progress of the video played using MPMoviePlayerController** in a **UILabel**. I need to show the current progress and the total duration of the video in a UILable. It should look something like 1.25/5.00 ? I need to show this when the video is playing. I can show it directly with the Default Progress Bar but i need to disable it. As i am not able to disable it i am planning to show the current progress of the video in a UILabel. Can someone please provide any suggestion on this?

Comment: It sounds like you have two questions.  #1) how to disable the default progress bar and #2) how to get the current progress as a property that you can put into a label somewhere else.  Am I correct in this?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: Yes Michael. I was actually looking on how to disable the default progress bar. But i was not able to find how to do that. So i just thought of hiding the controls using MPMovieControlStyleNone. But my requirement is to definitely the progress of the Video...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the Answer...

When Instantiating the Video Player...

```
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
```

//Add the Label to show the Progress of the Video....

```
progressLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,275,70,25)];
progressLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[progressLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:progressLabel];
```

//set a Timer..

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updatePlaybackTime:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

and in the Method updatePlaybackTime: ....

```
- (void)updatePlaybackTime:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime];
}
```

Done..U will have the Label updated with the progress of the Video...

Comment: yes this work too but the timer will continue even if u pause the player what means that u are wasting resources ;)

Comment: and u have to use MPMoviePlayerViewController... is nicer than MPMoviePlayerController ;)

Comment: I am having another notification to notify when the video pauses and stops. SO in that method, i am invalidating the timer. I just havent mentioned that in the above example.... Apart from this, How different is MPMoviePlayerViewController different from MPMoviePlayerController??? What extra does this provide other than ones provided by MPMoviePlayerController??

Comment: Well in xcode 3 there was an message about replacing MPMoviePlayerController to MPMoviePlayerViewController cause the first one would be depreciated, and for your timer u should get a interval of 0.5 cause if a video has a duration of .5 u should show another second...

Comment: and with movieplayer controller if u make a gesture of two fingers separating them the video will go to full screen mode, im sure that if u want to show the custm duration you dont want to enable this mode ;)

Answer (score 3):

well to set the progress and the durations, u can call a self watcher after playing the video and then update the value of progress Label...

you set the observer to see when the player started playing and in the selector u call to the watcher, this watcher should look something like this;

```
-(void)watcher{
   urProgressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",movieplayer.currentPlaybackTime];
   [self performSelector:@selector(watcher) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];//to update the value each 0.5 seconds 
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

In order to hide default progress bar checkout following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6518303/200272).
In order to have a custom progress bar checkout following links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197716/200272), [2](http://blog.engage-encore.com/index.php/2010/11/08/video-player-ipad-iphone/).